# Loop - what is the safest variable to use as the index

Tags: c++, loops, methods, int, unsigned

I would like to know if what's the safest and least memory absorbing methods to make loops in c++.
Does loop

```
for ( unsigned int i = 0;  i < 10; i++){..}
```

win over loop with just **int** instead of **unsigned int**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `int` and `unsigned int` variables take exactly the same amount of memory and represented in the resulting assembly code in exactly the same way. Thus adding `unsigned` here changes nothing from the performance point of view.

In general you should not worry. The loop counter is definitely not the biggest memory consuming thing in your program.

Comment: You should add that with other values, it could be different. Eg. too big values for signed, problems with unsigned if counted in the other cirection, undefined signed overflow etc.etc.